# SQL statements containing $ character are sucessfully passed through MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, binary-log

I have been figuring out mysqlbinlog restore issue for some days and I have found that it is caused by some uncomplete SQL statements which are containing $ character.

Following SQL statements are logged into the general log and also appear in the binary logs:

```
delete from build_type$
insert into build_type$ values ('bt3') 
delete from vcs_root_instance$
```

Why these statements passthrough (contatining $ symbol). Database is containing tables without $ symbol -  build_type, vcs_root_instance?

```
desc build_type;
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| int_id            | varchar(80) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| config_id         | varchar(80) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| origin_project_id | varchar(80) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| delete_time       | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

MariaDB version: 10.2.23

Answer (score 0):

Use backtics around database, table, and column names if they contain most special characters, including `$`.  (Underscore is OK.)  Example:

```
delete from `build_type$`
```

Better yet, don't use `$`.